# Cannot figure out how to turn off StrictHostKeyChecking

Tags: ssh

I've got this ssh command that I run on different databases:

`ssh -i $8 -l $9 $1  "set -o pipefail set -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no; mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables -u $2 -p$3 -P $4 -h $5 $6" | gzip -c > $7;`

The variables are arguments to this command.

It works except when the backend of an ip address changes, despite having `set -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no`, I get this message:

```
Offending ECDSA key in /home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:130
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/admin/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "172.30.0.63"
ECDSA host key for 172.30.0.63 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

There is something wrong with the command but I'm not sure where. I've tried a couple of different variations but wihtout success.

Comment: I really recommend using ansible or similar automation for things like this rather than one-liner scripts that I can guarantee you won't remember what they did or how to modify two years from now when something breaks.

Comment: Also, the reason you're getting this particular error is because the copy of the host's identity key *you have stored locally* doesn't match the one the remote host provides. Using the suggested command will clear the offending local key, and the next time you log in you'll be asked to confirm the remote key *once*, after which the error disappears.

Comment: It’s more to ensure things get backed up every night then fix a key for a server that moved to a different internal ip address.

Comment: If that's something that happens on a regular basis, *you are doing network topology wrong*.

Comment: AWS assigns new back-end ip addresses to cloned instances. Complain to them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` argument needs to be passed as an option to the ssh command, rather than as an option to the remote shell command. So for example:

```
ssh -i "$8" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l "$9" "$1"  "
  set -o pipefail; mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables -u $2 -p$3 -P $4 -h $5 $6
" | gzip -c > "$7"
```

(I double-quoted the parameter expansions here because, although you didn't mention which local shell you are using, many shells subject unquoted expansion to word splitting and filename generation.)

Note that this option does not suppress warnings about a possible MiM attack.

Comment: Addendum to note: Disabling strict host key checking is almost always a worse solution than *fixing the actual host keys*.

Answer (score 3):

If disabling at run time with command line options doesn't work, then disable it in your `~/.ssh/config` file. You can create the file if it doesn't exist,remember to give it `rw-r-r` permissions with
`chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config` or `rw-` with `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`, and add this:

```
 Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

check this post too:
[How to disable strict host key checking in ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh)

Comment: Note that this will disable StrictHostKeyChecking for _all_ servers this user `ssh`s to. I don't know if this is desired.

Comment: yes right, he can change the * to a specific ip/domain

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer not to bypass it all the time, inly when doing automated backups. The first comment from @terdon worked, though initially I thought it wasn't because I was still getting a warning.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to check the file permissions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not normally in the business of telling other people how to run their server administration, but...

**If you're in a position where you find yourself passing eight variables to a one-liner shell script, you are doing things horribly, *horribly* wrong.**

Let's start by simplifying this.

First, the SSH bit:

I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that each of those variables *is* actually variable, that you have multiple hosts, *each* of which needs to be accessed as a different user with a different identity file, *none* of which can be counted on to have a correct host key, and that you do not have the authority to change any of the above.

(I'll spare you a five-page invective-filled rant about consistency and proper security measures; take it as read)

Add the following to `~/.ssh/config` on whatever administrator account you intend to use for this:

```
Host foo
   StrictHostKeyChecking No
   HostName 172.30.0.63
   User foouser
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_foo.ed25519

Host bar
  StrictHostKeyChecking No
  HostName bar.internal.elsewhere
  User baruser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bar.ecdsa

Host qux
  StrictHostKeyChecking No
  HostName qux.eternal.universe
  User quxuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_qux.rsa
```

And so on. At this point you can omit `$8` and `$9` as well as the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking No` on the command line which, as steeldriver pointed out, was in the wrong place entirely to begin with.

Secondly, the mysqldump part.

This is where automation software like [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_db_module.html) shines.

First off, you create an ansible inventory as follows:

```yaml
all:
  dbservers:
    hosts:
      foo:
      bar:
      qux:
```

Use the same naming convention here as in your `~/.ssh/config` file. Use `ansible -m ping dbservers` to check if you got it right, correct errors as necessary.

Then add the following in `host_vars/baz/vars.yaml`:

```yaml
mysql_db_user: 'bazdbuser'
mysql_db_password: 'bazdbpassword'
mysql_db_port: 12345
mysql_db_host: 'baz-db.remote
mysql_db_dbs:
  - 'bazdb1'
  - 'bazdb2'
  - 'bazdb3'
mysql_dump_local_destination: '/backups/baz/'
```

Then create the following playbook anywhere, let's call it `make_backup_dumps.yaml`:

```yaml
---
- hosts: dbservers
  become: false
  tasks:
    - name: Dump requested databases.
      community.mysql.mysql_db:
        login_host: '{{ mysql_db_host }}'
        login_user: '{{ mysql_db_user }}'
        login_port: '{{ mysql_db_port }}'
        skip_lock_tables: true
        state: dump
        target: '/tmp/db_{{ ansible_host }}_{{ item }}.sql.gz'
      loop: {{ mysql_db_dbs }}

    - name: Retrieve remote dumps.
      ansible.builtin.fetch:
        src: '/tmp/db_{{ ansible_host }}_{{ item }}.sql.gz'
        dest: '{{ mysql_dump_local_destination }}'
      loop: {{ mysql_db_dbs }}
```

Test the script on one host with `ansible-playbook --limit foo make_backup_dumps.yaml`; if the output is to your liking, run it for all hosts with `ansible-playbook make_backup_dumps.yaml`.

This may be a bit bulkier than your one-liner, but it's significantly more readable, much easier to maintain, supports multiple database table dumps per host, will run in parallel on each host, *and will give you an overview of successes/failures for each step on each host, with optional levels of verbosity so you can troubleshoot*.

Whether you use it is up to you, but regardless, *for the love of GNU at the very least clear up your host keys because the error you're actually getting is something caused locally*.

Comment: I use rex, not ansible.

Comment: If that SSH one-liner is characteristic of rex scripting, I'm staying *far* away from it.

Comment: It’s just a Perl with helper functions to help automate running commands on a remote server. I prefer it to dealing with some other layer of abstraction.